# Exchange calendar events loading

Tags: api, outlook, calendar, exchange-server, filemaker

**Hi**

I have made a calendar for my app and I would like to load exchange event for my users and google events.

with google I have no problem.

with exchange I have problems.

I send to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token" and I receive a token. it's something like that.

```
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
```

after I receive this token I send to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars I want to receive the event sending

```
 http_setCustomHeader( "Authorization:"; "Bearer " &mcal_base_Kalender::sv_Exchange_Token);
```

and the code

I always receiving the same answer

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "34a55ca5-698e-43b7-b9e6-f725cfa5f670",
      "date": "2018-04-23T08:11:35"
    }
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me please??? If I am do something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your token isn't valid so the problem is with whatever code your using to generate it. Eg you should be able to take the token you produce and then parse it with a tool like https://jwt.io/ which doesn't work with what you have posted and is consistent with the error you receive back from the server.