# How to Delete and Rename Notebook name Using Onenote Graph API

Tags: office365, onenote, onenote-api

I want to rename notebook name. i tried below Graph request.

```
PATCH "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks{id}"
```

I am getting "UnknownError", What is PATCH Request url to rename notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote Notebooks are folders when exposed to the OneDrive api and can be [renamed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_update) or [deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delete).

The OneDrive documentation, however, specifically suggests not doing this with OneNote Notebooks.

sample php code to delete NoteBook (you would obtain {item-id} via https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: */*',
    'return-client-request-id: true','Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi…));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
```

The deleted Notebook is moved to the Recycle bin.

sample php code to rename NoteBook

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'{"name":"newname"}');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: */*',
    'return-client-request-id: true','Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi…));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i tried above code , i am getting  error message "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217".Please help me to solve this error

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976439/exchange-calendar-events-loading<br/>The answer suggests your token is not valid.

Comment: Thank you so much for your sample code my problem is solved

Comment: how can i change drive file permission to ready only please suggest

Comment: Hi Mohammad, please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369351/how-set-onenote-page-as-read-only-using-onenote-api?noredirect=1&lq=1 for a suggested solution. I suspect you can only share an item as read only, not actually set the item to read only.

Comment: how can i upload image file from my server to onedrive folder , please suggest POST or PATCH request method

Comment: Hi Mohammad, This is explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/upload, for small files <4MB a direct upload of the data is available, for larger files they must be split into 60MB chunks. The correct syntax is CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT'

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. You might want to add this to our uservoice.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis